# SELECT Within a SELECT Different WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT TASK_ID, INVOICED, DELETE_WEEK,
SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) AS hours
FROM b_report_week
WHERE INVOICE = 1 AND DELETE_WEEK = 0
GROUP BY TASK_ID
```

I need to add another SELECT statement with a SUM within this query to provide a result:

```
WHERE INVOICE = 0
```

Instead of the 1 in the previous statement.  It still needs to be grouped by TASK_ID and DELETE_WEEK still needs to be 0.  I've tried this:

```
SELECT TASK_ID, INVOICED, DELETE_WEEK,
SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) AS hours,
(SELECT SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) AS hours2 
FROM b_report_week WHERE INVOICE = 0 AND DELETE_WEEK = 0 GROUP BY TASK_ID)
FROM b_report_week
WHERE INVOICE = 1 AND DELETE_WEEK = 0
GROUP BY TASK_ID
```

But this is obviously incorrect.  I'm needing to use the hours and hours2 in outputting the correct results within a PHP while loop which I have.  Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you could use  [Case](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statements:

```
SELECT TASK_ID, INVOICED, DELETE_WEEK,
case when INVOICE = 1 then SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) else 0 end AS hours,
case when INVOICE = 0 then SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) else 0 end AS hours2,
FROM b_report_week
WHERE DELETE_WEEK = 0
GROUP BY TASK_ID
```

(Note - the where clause had to change to avoid restricting the results to Invoice = 1.)

Comment: Needed to change case when INVOICE to INVOICED.. But this is along the right lines.  However when I get the result for hours: $taskTotalHours = $row['hours']; It seems to be adding both the INVOICED = 1 and INVOICED = 0. Any idea why?

Comment: I don't, I mocked something up and noticed I had to put Invoice in the group by, but the results were consistent

Answer (score 0):

use [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)

```
SELECT TASK_ID, INVOICED, DELETE_WEEK,
SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) AS hours , 
SUM(CASE WHEN INVOICE = 0 then MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL else o end case) as custom_sum
FROM b_report_week
WHERE DELETE_WEEK = 0
GROUP BY TASK_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could solve it with an UNION clause

```
SELECT TASK_ID, INVOICED, DELETE_WEEK,
SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) AS hours
FROM b_report_week
WHERE INVOICE = 1 AND DELETE_WEEK = 0
GROUP BY TASK_ID
UNION
SELECT TASK_ID, INVOICED, DELETE_WEEK,
SUM(MON_BILL+TUE_BILL+WED_BILL+THU_BILL+FRI_BILL) AS hours
FROM b_report_week
WHERE INVOICE = 0 AND DELETE_WEEK = 0
GROUP BY TASK_ID
```

but I think it more easy to read the CASE WHEN clause